# Where can I get debug symbols (PDB) for Windows.Live.dll?

Tags: debugging, windows-phone, debug-symbols, live-sdk

I am using the Microsoft [Live SDK for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/live/ff621310) to access SkyDrive and get an exception in **Microsoft.Live.dll**. I'd like to step through the source to debug the issue, but fetching symbols from symbol server http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols fails.

I followed [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#using_the_microsoft_symbol_server) on how to set up the symbol server in my dev environment. The environment variable `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` is set to **srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols**. This seems to work for other assemblies. While debugging I see the symbol cache at **c:\symbols** grow with entries, but **Microsoft.Live** is missing.

Where can I get debug symbols for Microsoft.Live.dll?

Comment: Microsoft provides public symbols for only a subset of their binaries. It's possible that Microsoft.Live.dll is not part of that subset.